MySQL table_open_cache miss 100% on query spikes
We encountered a situation where we had multiple connections opened to our DB, which seems to cause a high rate of open table cache misses.
I would expect that in this kind of situation we see 100% cache utilisation, but the opposite happened, hit rate was reduced to 0%.
When query rate went down we saw that cache usage increased back to 100%
Do you have any idea what might cuase that?

Take a look at these values
innodb open files = 10000 or higher.
table_open_cache = 20000
table_definition_cache = 10000

You can get the current values ​​like this
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_open_files';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table_open_cache';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table_definition_cache';

And so you can check whether tables are opened again and again. Info: Flush, dump, etc, also flush the cache
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Open_tables';
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Opened_tables';

For very large DBs you should also check whether the OS (linux) can do this. Otherwise you'll have to change it

I know the above variables, the issue is that under certain load the cache is not used at all, i.e open_cache_misses is 100% and open_cache_hits is 0.
